# What does createBlock do ? [Magento]

Tags: magento

What do the parameters mean in createBlock ?

```
createBlock('adminhtml/customer', 'customer')
```

Also, where can I find documentation to all the functions of magento ?

Answer (score 0):

`Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock()` is the factory method for block class instantiation. The first argument is either a complete class name or the so-called classgroup notation which resolves class names against the configuration (e.g. "adminhtml" points to the configured class prefix "Mage_Adminhtml_Block", thus giving the class name "Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer"). The factory method allows for runtime configuration-based rewriting of class names.

Theoretically, all functions are documented in the code. There is no documentation for Magento 1. Magento 2 does have a documentation initiative: https://wiki.magento.com/display/MAGE2DOC/Magento+2+Product+Documentation

Comment: Thanks ! What would the second paramter be ?

Comment: The teacher in me won't let me answer that until I know you've tried to determine it for yourself. Will you look at the method definition and then tell me what you think it does? That will be much better than just getting an answer from me :-)

Comment: Sure :) Although, I changed/remove the second paramter "customer". But nothing seemed to have changed. The block continued working just the same.